# Excel VBA 10 Buttons with almost the same code

Tags: excel, vba, userform

This is just about making my code look better.

I have a userform with 10 buttons, each of the button activates the same sub but with a different input.

I was wondering if there is a way to make the code shorter and nicer.

This is basically what i have right now:

```
Private Sub 10_Click()

info (10000)

End Sub

Private Sub 20_Click()

info (20000)

End Sub

Private Sub 30_Click()

info (30000)

End Sub

Private Sub 40_Click()

info (40000)

End Sub

Private Sub 50_Click()

info (50000)

End Sub

Private Sub 60_Click()

info (60000)

End Sub

Private Sub 70_Click()

info (70000)

End Sub

Private Sub 80_Click()

info (80000)

End Sub

Private Sub 90_Click()

info (90000)

End Sub

Private Sub 100_Click()

info  (100000)

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Each button is an independent control so no,  there is no way with this design. Maybe you could design the userform to have a single button and a textbox (or dropdown list) wheere you type the value (1000, 2000, and so on) and a single sub to handle it.

Comment: For starters, remove the empty lines, indent, and remove the parentheses in the *info* lines.

Comment: The code looks like you've named your buttons `10`, `20`, etc.  That gives me a "Not a legal object name" error.

Answer (score -1):

It is a little difficult to help without knowing what "Info" is supposed to do, but here is something to get you started.

Rename your buttons "btn10", "btn20", etcetera.

In your UserForm, use this code. (No need for individual button code.)

```
Private btnInfo() As New clsInfoButtons

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim lngButtonNumber As Long
    
    For lngButtonNumber = 1 To 10
    
        ReDim Preserve btnInfo(1 To lngButtonNumber)
    
        Set btnInfo(lngButtonNumber).btnInfoButtons = Me.Controls("btn" & (lngButtonNumber * 10))
    
    Next lngButtonNumber

End Sub
```

Now create a Class Module and call it "clsInfoButtons".

Inside the Class Module add this code.

```
Public WithEvents btnInfoButtons As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub btnInfoButtons_Click()

    MsgBox Replace(btnInfoButtons.Name, "btn", vbNullString)

End Sub
```

Just so you know, you can use Class Modules for Labels, TextBoxes etcetera too. Not only does it decrease the overall code, it reduces the potential for error because you can write the same code for all included controls.